# Tracking changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git

Is it possible to set up Visual Studio (2010) for tracking changes (left color symbols) not from last file open state, but from source control commited state? This is how netbeans works and it is really great feature, especially reverting text block from editor by right click... Visual Studio default tracking mode is not much useful.

**EDIT 1:**
Something like this way:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Now it works with latest Git Source Control Provider (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) extension. Good job, extension developers. Left bar is standard visual studio tracker, right bar is tracker tracking changes against last commit. See picture:

[image]

**EDIT 3 (12/05/2015):**
Now I use standard VS git tools and for change tracking great  `Git Diff Margin` extension. I use it with VS2013 and 2015 and it works very well. See:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I have it installed. I see changed files in solution explorer, but it is not what I am talking about. In Netbeans changes are visible based on rows (using colored marks as visual studio use for tracking changes from file opening), not only by files.

Comment: I know you have tagged `git`, so I don't know if it's of interest but Mercurial under [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) along with the Visual Studio plugin [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) works very well. I'm making this a comment rather than answer because of the `git` tag

Comment: After see your image in the update, VisualHG does *not* provide that facility, it is purely for the status of the file to be displayed in the project/solution explorer... so *not* what you're looking for, sorry

Comment: There is currently no add-on or feature in Visual Studio to provide this functionality.

Comment: See EDIT 3 for the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For people like me that skim straight to the answer -

> OP (12/05/2015) - Now I use standard VS git tools and for change tracking great Git Diff Margin extension. I use it with VS2013 and 2015 and it works very well

[Git Diff Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin)

Works great for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like if you have Visual Studio 2013, and you're working with GIT, it does work.

[image]

Also, you can see what happens in the Team Explorer tab.

[image]

Comment: I think this is only normal file state tracker. But with latest version of Git Source Control Provider (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) it is working now also in VS2010. Then there are two trackers side by side.

Comment: 2 ?? that's 2 more than most people will ever use :) / :(
Other than that, I actually find going to Git Extensions, or Git Bash when I need to :) not sure why though ...

Comment: guess VS is not for mac devs, since there's only `.vsix` there and not `.mpack` or whatever it's called

Answer (score 0):

There is no such facility in VS to do this. I rely on CTRL-Z to undo. If there are too many changes, you can do a `git checkout -p -- .` which will walk you through all the differences and apply the ones you need. The `-p` (or `--patch`) parameter is available on `git reset`, `git add` and `git checkout`.

That being said, one could write an add-in to VS to give you this view.

Also, I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to move back and forth between my recent cursor positions.